# How to parse XML file from sdcard using Dom

Tags: java, android

I want to parse xml file from sdcard. i used DOM concept. here i attached the code

```
InputStream filename = null;
    Document obj_doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory doc_build_fact = null;
    DocumentBuilder doc_builder = null;
    filename = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/filename.xml");
    doc_build_fact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    doc_builder = doc_build_fact.newDocumentBuilder();

    obj_doc = doc_builder.parse(filename);

    NodeList obj_nod_list = null;
    if (null != obj_doc) {
        org.w3c.dom.Element feed = obj_doc.getDocumentElement();
        obj_nod_list = feed.getElementsByTagName("MyTag"); 
    }
```

I dont know how to get a String from xml file. can anyone guide me to get a string variable from xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initialization of the DocumentBuilder etc. looks correct.

How does your XML file look like? If you have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<moviedatabase>
  <movie>
    <title>Ace Ventura</title>
    <year>1995</year>
  </movie>

  <movie>
    <title>Elisabethtown</title>
    <year>2005</year>
  </movie>
</moviedatabase>
```

You could obtain all movies in a NodeList like this first:

```
Element root = obj_root.getDocumentElement();
NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("movie");
```

Then you could obtain the title string as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {           
    Node item = items.item(i);
    NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
            Node property = properties.item(j);
        String name = property.getNodeName();
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
             // Store it where you want
             String myTitle = property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 
        }
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("year")) {
             String year = property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 
        }
    }
}
```

You can find further information for DOM parsing [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) at section: Working with DOM

Enjoy

Comment: Thank you saxos. I got solution, keep answering.